# Primefaces 6.2: p:downloadFile inside commandButton with ajax=true

Tags: primefaces

I have following component:

```
                <p:commandButton style="width: 186px" title="#{msg['menu.export.tab.column.download']}"
                             ajax="false"
                             rendered="#{fileExist and not fileNull}"
                             styleClass="button -primary download-file -md -margin-right-25 push-20 icon-file-pdf -width-max-content">
                <p:fileDownload value="#{employeeExport.getExportDataXLS(export)}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
```

It works for me, but I want to disable this button after click, and enable it oncomplete (after file download) for prevent user to click multiple times before file from first request is ready to downloa

I add this lines to my p:commandButton,

```
                             onclick="$('.icon-file-pdf').addClass('disabled'); console.log('disabled');"
                             oncomplete="$('.icon-file-pdf').removeClass('disabled');
```

but oncomplete action is not firing cause ajax=false.
If i change ajax=true, both actions - oncomplete and onlick are firing, but there is no downloaded file in this case.

Do You know how to fire onclick and oncomplete action with ability to download file?

Answer (score 3):

Ajax file downloading in PrimeFaces is [available since version 10](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5978). So, one option would be upgrading your PrimeFaces (I would advice to do so, and upgrade to the latest version while you're at it).

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot upgrade PF right now :| Any other option to do it without ajax or it's impossible?

Comment: I also tried onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start,stop)", but start and stop functions are fired in same time, not before and after download

Comment: Only ajax="false" is supported in any version before PF 10.  No workarounds.